# Important logs notifications - ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: notification, log

Some notifications appear on my system logs with the status "important".

```
gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)

kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20201113/psparse-529)
kernel: ACPI Error: Thread 2161368128 cannot release Mutex [ECMX]
acquired by thread 2165448384 (20201113/exmutex-378)

kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS

(gdm3)GLib: Source ID 135 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-session-b)CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

(systemd-udevd)veth1167451: Failed to get link config: No such device
```

What do these notifications mean? Do I need to fix them?

Comment: What issues? Do you actually have a problem or are you concerned about messages you don't understand? Please edit the question accordingly, i.e., IF you have a problem make sure to  describe it.

Comment: thanks for your response, I haven't any problem on my ubuntu, what do these messages mean?

Comment: These are not for you and the kernel notices are bugs in your hardware.